# XMLHttpRequest for http:// required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and preflight only happen in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a front-end developer. I'm coding only with client side so I don't know for sure about the error exist. I've searching about CORS, but still no idea what did my problem course.

I'm trying to post data to REST.

```
$.ajax({
     url        : urlPost,
     type       : "POST",
     data       : JSON.stringify(obj),
     dataType   : "json",
     contentType: "application/json",

     success: function(res){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
     },

     error: function(res){
         console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
     }
});
```

Headers of web service show in firebug of firedfox :

[image]

It is working for all the browser that I used, except in IE 10, I got two errors:

1. SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for `http://mysite/project/wl.svc/AddWL/` required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
2. SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for `http://mysite/project/wl.svc/AddWL/` required CORS preflight.

Comment: Is the urlPost to same domain where from document was loaded? Are you using SSL? Is the document inside IFRAME? 

In any case, CORS will need special headers from server to work. It can not be configured only from client side.

Comment: But I wonder, it works well with Chrome, Firefox excepts IE.

Comment: urlPost is in different domain with document loading domain. I updated my question with the Headers.

Comment: Check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: Showing the headers in Firefox doesn't do much to track down the problem, since there isn't a problem in that browser!

Comment: @TeemuIkonen : Ooops so I have to change all my code from `jQuery.ajax` to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I think jQuery supports cors: http://danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/01/18/getting-cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-complex-jquery-ajax-requests/

Comment: @TeemuIkonen : I added `xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },` to `$.ajax`, but still giving same error.

Comment: jQuery does not support CORS requests in IE<10. If you want to perform CORS requests in IE<10 with jquery, you must either extend jquery's ajax method with a new transport that supports IE XDomainRequest, or not use jQuery to perform your ajax.

Comment: Is there a means to take care of this in C# within the codebehind?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646732/sec7118-xmlhttprequest-cors-ie-console-message#32850937) can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think  you have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), so I recommend you to take a look at [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

I have used it and it works fine all what you need to append your request url to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ which it is a Proxy server to request the chosen URL

```
var cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + urlPost;

$.ajax({
     url        : cors_api_url,
     type       : "POST",
     data       : JSON.stringify(obj),
     dataType   : "json",
     contentType: "application/json",

     success: function(res){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
     },

     error: function(res){
         console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
     }
});
```