# SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest CORS - IE Console message

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cors, internet-explorer-10

I am using CORS POST request with everything taken care as given @http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Server sets Response header to:
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' and I can see this header value in IE developer tool.

But on IE10 browser I see console message as "SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http:// required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

When I check on Microsoft site it has below given explanation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn423949(v=vs.94).aspx

***SEC7118***

***Description:***
*"XMLHttpRequest for [URL] required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). "
An XMLHttpRequest was made to a domain that was different than your page's domain. This requires the server to return an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in its response headers, but one was not returned.*

***Suggested Fix:***
*The server must support CORS requests and return an appropriate "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header with the resource. See CORS for XHR in IE10 for more info about CORS in response headers.*

**Questions:**

1. I want to know if this console message is an ERROR ??
2. Will this cause any failures ??
3. Why do I get this message even after setting response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  value to '*'??
4. Does 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  value has to be origin name for
   IE10 to work? I know * is not a very good option, But does IE
   requires exact origin name ??

[image]

[image]

I kept URL's and cookie details hidden from these images.

Comment: Can you share your client code and headers as seen from IE F12 developer panel?

Comment: Can you include the *response* headers as seen in that panel?

Comment: What is the URL of the document that the request is coming from? (Most importantly, what is the scheme part of that URL?)

Comment: Have you tested this in any other browsers? They might give you more helpful error messages.

Comment: Just checking - that is the response for the Ajax request, not the initial HTML document, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I tested with chrome browser it works all good. with no errors no console messages

Comment: Just checking - that is the response for the Ajax request, not the initial HTML document, isn't it? - I did not understand this question? Response served by server will be an image..

Comment: You type a URL into the address bar. The browser makes an HTTP request. The server sends back an HTML document. That HTML document loads some JavaScript. That JavaScript uses XMLHttpRequest to make *another* HTTP request. The server responds to that request. Are you showing us the details of the HTTP response for the first HTTP request I described (trigged by the address bar) or the second (triggered by JavaScript)?

Comment: request and response headers are for - the second (triggered by JavaScript) -

Comment: request and response headers are for cors request from js - the second (triggered by JavaScript)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I own both domains, the one with the site, and the one to which I send AJAX requests (API site). Both use valid SSL certificates, and API site SENDS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header set exactly to requesting site URL (not asterisk). All perfectly by the book, I mean CORS specification. SO: WHY WARNING? I know every byte sent from API site, because I've made custom WCF service which sends appropriate headers (yes, I made workarounds for known .NET and IE quirks and tested it with IE8 to IE11). It works, but the warning (INFORMATION to be exact) is annoying.

Comment: @Harry I had the same scenario as you and I got the warning but it wasn't working for me.  Not sure what is going on!

Answer (score 11):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn423949(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Security error codes are in the form SEC7xxx [In IE]

Pertaining to SEC7118:

> An XMLHttpRequest was made to a domain that was different than your page's domain. This requires the server to return an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in its response headers, but one was not returned.
>
> Note  This error code was removed in IE11 on Windows 10. It remains in IE11 for Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.

So it is technically viewed as an error from IE's perspective, but certainly isn't one (hence why it is going away). Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set on a resource, but isn't necessarily sent back with the request. If a specified resource DOESN'T have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (or a domain), the resource would not be accessible and the server would likely return a 503 or 404 and you would see a true error message in the console similar to the below:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://blog.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: what do you mean 'set on a resource but isn't necessarily sent back' ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered `SEC7118` when CORS was set up correctly. I verified that the requests were completing with status 200 using the network debugger. So, you can disregard this message if your application is otherwise functioning properly.

Comment: Yes.. but want to know whats the exact reasoning behind this kind of behaviour

Comment: Probably just poor implementation in IE. No other browsers seem to have this problem, and it does not stop anything from working; it is just a spurious warning message.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error in IE11:

> SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http:// required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Adding the following to my `.htaccess` fixed it:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Answer (score -3):

I had this same issue. It has to do with Internet Explorer's handing of third party cookies. You can fix this issue by going into Tools>Internet Options then selecting the Privacy tab. If you change the setting to "Accept All Cookies" you will no longer see that message.

The safer way to do this would be to click on the "Sites" button and allow cookies from your site's url.

[image]

Comment: This does not really help the website developer. One cannot require all the website visitors to change their privacy settings.

Comment: true but this can fix only for your machine.. does not fix issue with your webpage

Comment: Upvoted because this is actually the best answer, even if it's not exactly what the OP was hoping for ...

Comment: Tried all possible settings inside the IE settings but nothing changed anything to the situation.